# Is Sasuke's teleportation technique just substitution jutsu?

Tags: naruto

Sasuke's new teleportation technique feels like [Body Replacement Technique](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Body_Replacement_Technique)

What is the difference between these two techniques?

Answer (score 3):

Sasuke's new teleportation technique is called [Amenotejikara](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amenotejikara)

> With his left eye, Sasuke instantly shifts the location of himself,
>   others, and objects, within a certain range. This range can be
>   increased if he swaps himself with an object, as seen when he switched
>   places with Sakura Haruno's discarded flak jacket. Using the chakra
>   of the nine tailed beasts allowed Sasuke to extend the range of this
>   technique even further, as seen when he shifted him and his Susanoo
>   behind Naruto Uzumaki, who was a considerable distance away.
>
> Due to its speed, this technique has proven to be especially useful
>   for launching surprise attacks against enemies.

In  Body Replacement Technique you have to replace your body with an object but in Amenotejikara it's not compulsory. Body Replacement Technique can be learned by any ninja but Amenotejikara seems to be limited to Rinnegan user only.

Few more points to be noted here:

> - At certain times, the technique has to be recharged and cannot be
>     used.
> - This technique not only switches the position, but the momentum and
>     direction of the switched targets as well - [src](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Amenotejikara)